# Button gets enabled on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've 2 buttons in my HTML page, first one is enabled and the second one is disabled and when I click the first the first one, the first one gets disabled and the second one is enabled and the same goes with the second button, when I click the second button (When this gets enabled), the first one gets disabled, and this is working totally fine. Here I came up finding this problem when I did a refresh accidentally.

I click the first button, the second gets enabled, disabling the first one. After a refresh it goes to the initial state, i.e., the first gets enabled and second is disabled.

Below is the piece of code.

```
<tr>
    <td>SubTask</td>
    <td>
       <select id="subtask" name="subtask">
           <option value="Subtask">Subtask</option>
       </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Start" name="Start" id="Start" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Stop" name="Stop" id="Stop" disabled="disabled" /></td>
</tr>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var form = $('#formSec');
        var task = document.getElementById('task');
        var subtask = $('#subtask');
        $('#Start').on("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "UpdateStartTime",
                data : form.serialize(),
                success : function() {
                    $('#task').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#subtask').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#Start').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#Stop').attr("disabled", false);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

        $('#Stop').on("click", function() {
            var form = $('#formSec');
            var task = document.getElementById('task');
            var subtask = $('#subtask');
            $.ajax({
                type : "post",
                url : "UpdateEndTime",
                data : form.serialize(),
                success : function() {
                    $('#task').attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#subtask').attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#Start').attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#Stop').attr("disabled", true);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

There is some posting functionality added in the `js` above, please ignore it.

Comment: if you mean a refresh as in reloading the page that's normal. A web page is stateless. You need to store the state somewhere and reload it on page refresh.

Comment: If you want your button states to be consistent after a refresh, you need to save the states somewhere. Possible "locations": cookies, localStorage, sessionStorage, server.

Comment: So how do you want your markup to know which button should have `disabled` attribute on page load? You should store some data in `localStorage` / database / controller etc. defining the state of your page

Comment: When you call updateEndTime or updateStartTime, I would set a variable like Boolean blnstart (true if updateStartTime was clicked).  Then when you  actually call this page, you can use: ''if(blnstart){$('#Start').trigger('click')}else..''

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/30144363?s=2|1.3568#30144363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can achieve this by setting a variable to localStorage. That will give you the facility to access the tiggered button.

Such as:

```
$('#Start').on("click", function() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.setItem("clickStat", "start");
  }
});
```

similarly..

```
$('#Stop').on("click", function() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.setItem("clickStat", "stop");
  }
});
```

The access that in this way:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
   var stat = localStorage.getItem("clickStat");
   if(stat == "start"){
     $('#Start').attr("disabled", true);
     $('#Stop').attr("disabled", false);
   }else{
     $('#Start').attr("disabled", false);
     $('#Stop').attr("disabled", true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, You are life saviour, But there is another problem that's coming, When I re login into my app, if i click the button and close my window and again when I login, it is still showing the disabled button :(, any workaround for this?

Comment: Hey Thanks Alot Man, I found it, just used `localStorage.clear();`, in my login.jsp :)

Comment: Rakesh, one thing I would like to say, that localStorage.clear(); will remove all data stored in localStorage. That is a major drawback if you have multiple variable storage.

Use this: localStorage.removeItem(clickStat);

Thanks... you will get result as you needed.

Comment: And related to auto relogin after window close, you can again remove Item from localStorage, on window.onunload event, this will clear your variable from local storage when your window is in closing state. So to next app opening state you will not find any such variable in your localStorage... :)

Answer (score 0):

When you update the button state, save it to `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem("btn1enabled", false);
localStorage.setItem("btn2enabled, true);
```

Then, when you load the page, you can enabled/disabled the buttons based on what

`localStorage.getItem("btn1enabled");` and `localStorage.getItem("btn2enabled");`

give you.

(note: localStorage won't have anything saved the first time you load the page, so you will have to consider that case in code)